# 열 짱라고요? (열 + 장 = 열 짱?)

Tags: grammar, spoken-korean

I was watching a drama and the character who was buying lottery tickets said:

> 열 장이요

but it sounded to my ears like

> /열 짱이요/.

I have never seen fortis (i.e. tensing) happen this way and would like to know what rule is being applied here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the **표준어 규정의 조항** (roughly translated as the Provisions of the Rules of the Standard Language) Volume 2, Chapter 5, Section 26, it says the following:

***‘ㄹ’ 받침 뒤에 연결되는 ‘ㄷ, ㅅ, ㅈ’은 된소리로 발음한다***

That is to say, should the character begin with a ㅈ but is after a character whose bottom consonant is a ㄹ, then ㅈ becomes a ㅉ which is a 된소리. **된소리** is any of the following 5:

***ㄲ, ㄸ, ㅃ, ㅆ, ㅉ***

Another useful rule in the same chapter but in Section 23 states the following:

***받침 ‘ㄱ(ㄲ, ㅋ, ㄳ, ㄺ), ㄷ(ㅅ, ㅆ, ㅈ, ㅊ, ㅌ), ㅂ(ㅍ, ㄼ, ㄿ, ㅄ)’ 뒤에 연결되는 ‘ㄱ, ㄷ, ㅂ, ㅅ, ㅈ’은 된소리로 발음한다***

Take these two rules into account and now the following should make sense:

한장 (장 pronounced as is)

두장 (장 pronounced as is)

세장 (장 pronounced as is)

네장 (장 pronounced as is)

다섯장 (pronounced 다섯***짱***)

여섯장 (pronounced 여섯***짱***)

일곱장 (pronounced 일곱***짱***)

여덟장 (pronounced 여덜***짱***)

아홉장 (pronounced 아홉***짱***)

열장 (pronounced 열***짱***)

몇장 (pronounced 며***짱***) where 몇 means "any number"

Comment: Hi, sorry to necro, but I was reviewing my notes and realised that I already had a similar note. I tought this tensing rule (with ㄹ) only worked for sino-korean words:

"Sino-korean words where a syllable ends with ㄹ and the following syllable begins with ㄷ,ㅅ or ㅈ are changed to their double counterpart." 
I do not think this counts as a sino-korean compound. Secondly, I thought the number and the counter would be separate and so that would not apply also... can you comment at all? Thanks.

Comment: Oh no, I really don't think it's the case that it's limited to Sino-Korean words only. This rule applies to all Korean syllables regardless.